# .net REST will not return 0 values

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

I have a .net RESTful web service that makes a call to update the value of a product.  Whatever the new value is, I need to return that in json.  If the value gets updated to '0', it is not exposed in the json return value.  I need to make sure all values are returned.  thanks in advance.